# Acceleration of Centre of Mass immediately after the application of Force

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics

I read it in my physics textbook about the application of Force on Rigid Bodies and there I came across this case:-
[image: F is the Force which is applied and it is applied at an angle]

So now here when force is applied to this rod which is fixed at an end [represented by cross symbol] i.e.. it can rotate about that axis; it was given that angular velocity is zero just after the application of force...I am wondering why it is zero??